# IBM MQ explorer and standalone java client with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I have a IBM MQ manager with SSL enabled .I can connect with MQ explorer with SSL keystore.
But if i try with a standalone Java client and same keystore , I am not able to connect.
I can see error messages as No X.509 selected and unavailable authentication scheme messages in the ssl logs and client is sending a empty certificate.

> Standalone Java client : uses IBM JDK , java full version JRE 1.8.0 IBM
> Windows AMD 64 build 8.0.7.20 - pwa6480sr7fp20-20221020_01(SR7 FP20),
> Cipher suite used in Java client:
> SSL_ECHDE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>
> IBM MQ explorer version 9.1 ,Internal JRE: java full version JRE 1.8.0
> IBM Windows AMD 64 build 8.0.5.41 - pwa6480sr5fp41-20190919_01(SR5
> FP41),
>
> Cipher Suite on the Queue manager end ECHDE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Same keystore used on both.( keystore doesn't have password).

Can anyone suggest what would be the issue here?

Comment: What is the difference between the environments used in each case? Same Java? What version? Also, what cipher suite is in use in the Java program, and on the queue manager?

Comment: @MoragHughson have updated the questions with the details. Please suggest further

Comment: Do you also use the same _Trustsore_ for both ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell - yes Same keystore /truststore used on both mq explorer and java client     ( keystore/truststore doesn't have password)

Comment: Read again, I am talking about the **Truststore**, not the _keystore_. It is necessary for the client to authenticate the server, the client's certificate comes later.

Comment: @EugèneAdell -- yes i have a single jks which both acts as keystore and truststore. It contains the client cert, and the intermediate and root certs.. the intermediate and root certs are the same as Queue manager ones. Same is used on MQ explorer to connect.

Comment: there are many causes leading to SSL handshake failure : protocol versions, extensions, client options, software bugs.. My suggestion is you to make a capture and check what's inside.

Comment: Is there a MQ explorer open source code which i can use it and try as i dont see any difference on the SDK

Comment: Can you run a jms trace on the client app as well as a java ssl debug? You need to show how you pass the key store and trust store to the client app as well as you code around setting up the connection: channel, host, port, cipher for example.   Asking how to fix a problem without providing details is why no one has answered.

Comment: Which API is your program written in?   IBM MQ classes for Java or IBM MQ classes for JMS?

Comment: its IBM MQ classes for Java

Comment: What about my other questions? No one can help you with the very limited amount of data you provided.

Comment: Have you tried enabling SSL logs by passing this parameter to your standalone program: `-Djavax.net.debug=all`?